# Websocket or Server-sent events?

Tags: websocket, server-sent-events

If I need to show text being written on one browser card on another browser card, What is better? Websocket or Server-sent events?

Comment: text being written ? this application needs to update very frequently (*if some user is writing something*), I guess in this case websockets is feasible more than sending a request every second (*or less*) to the server from all the clients to get the updates whether there is some user is writing now or not.